# resolving single quote inside a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function call where my ${v.a} is getting 
resolved to name like  CNX'ion  .so My call is failing because in the end it has three quotes like

```
 <a href="javascript:editVendorDetails('${v.a}')// this changing into 

 <a href="javascript:editVendorDetails('CNX'ion')//have three quotes
```

can any one tell me how to get value of ${v.a} in my js function which may have quotes inside as explained above

Answer (score 0):

use can use JSON.stringify('${v.a}')